# Sound from video is very low whereas mp3 file sound is good

Tags: sound

I have tried in VLC as well as totem, when I play a mp3 files sound is good but sound from video is muffled. I am using hp pavilion dv6. Please let me know for any other info. I am new to ubuntu

Comment: Can you provide examples for videos and MP3 files, that exhibit the described behaviour? Only use short excerpts or build some yourself, if you want to avoid large file transfers or copyright issues.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. My internet is very slow. I am not able to upload. The same video works fine in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this sometimes, where certain media plays softer or louder than other media.  The simple fix I use is to open up the Sound Settings and set it to higher than 100% manually (you may have to click "Allow Louder than 100%" to do this, depending where you access the volume settings from).  I find that when I push the volume louder than 100%, videos that are otherwise too quiet can be heard much better.  If you do this simple fix, you may find that you'll have to turn it down again for your MP3's or it will get distorted/be too loud.

See below, I have where 100% is circled, and it's possible to go beyond it.

[image]